# How to grant read access to a ServiceAccount

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, backend, firebase-admin

[image: How to double check the read access for the Json file]

**I want to double check or consider another ways to set up the privileges that I have for this file.**

I've already tried **IAM** (Identity and Access Management) admin privileges (It has Editor privileges) & I'm using **GAE** (Google App Engine) with **Firebase Admin (It supposed to doesn't matter the Firebase Rules for the full privileges case)**.

I also have my file under /WEB-INF/.

**This is the error on the StackDriver**

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/WEB-INF/project-blah-firebase-adminsdk-blah-blah.json" "read")

**Additional notes**

1. I have tried the code on the Post and Get Method of a Servlet Class
2. I have tried **getApplicationDefault()**
3. Should I consider OAuth 2.0? if yes, where should I place the Application ID?

**Additional Reference**

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio?authuser=1#adding_firebase_iam_permissions_for_the_service_account

Comment: Make the URL absolute, not relative. So: WEB-INF/[PRIVA.....ETC

Comment: If I try it absolute like "C:..// its not going to work. it says file is missing. doing it by relative is the unique way to recognize it.

Comment: I'm talking about the image of the code

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar GAE project where I use Maven to manage/deploy my project. Here's what I do:

1. Put the json file into the `src/main/resources` directory.
2. Load the file as follows:

`InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("service_account.json");`